# Linear algebra set of real numbers, closed under addition?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the set defined as $S=\{[a,b,c]:a+b=0,a+c=0\}$, and addition by $[a,b,c]+[x,y,z]=[a,b+y,c] $

a) Is $S$ closed under this definition of addition? Explain fully.

b) Does this definition of addition have the commutative property? Explain fully.

c) Does the set have a zero vector? If it does, what is it? If it does not, explain why not.

d) Does every element of $S$ have an additive inverse? If yes, find the additive inverse of a generic element.  If not, give an example of an element in $S$ that does not have an additive inverse and explain why it does not have an additive inverse.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Have you, for example, written down some elements of $S$ and tried adding them up using your rule?

Comment: I am really just having trouble figuring out the process to solve this type of problem for future reference. I believe that it is not closed under addition, yet the definition of addition has the commutative property. For c and d, I do not know how to go about answering what it is asking.

Comment: Well, can you write out a few examples of elements of $S$ and try adding them up?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming via the title that $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3}.$

Before attempting this problem, it may be best to see what elements of $S$ are like. Since $a+b=0$, $b=-a$ and similarly, $c=-a$. Therefore, we can think of $S$ as $$S=\{[a,-a,-a]\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\}.$$

( a ) To show a set is not closed under addition, it suffices to provide a counterexample. Often, these examples may not be particularly obvious. It may be best to approach the problem as if you are trying to prove it is true and then when you run into a problem, you can see how to find an example that would go against the claim.

Let $[a,-a,-a],[b,-b,-b]\in S$. Then $$[a,-a,-a]+[b,-b,-b]=[a,-a-b,-a].$$ Since $a-(a+b)=-b$, and $b$ is not necessarily zero, this should show you where the closure property will fail. Now, see if you can provide a counterexample.

( b ) Since it seems that you believe this to be a commutative operation, let's see if we can prove it. Let $[a,-a,-a],[b,-b,-b]\in S$. Then $$[a,-a,-a]+[b,-b,-b]=[a,-a-b,-a]$$ $$\text{and}$$ $$[b,-b,-b]+[a,-a,-a]=[b,-b-a,-b].$$ It doesn't look to me like the right hand side of the above two equalities are the same. Try to provided a counterexample to the commutativity of the operation.

( c ) Here, you have a choice to make. If you believe there to be a zero vector, propose one and see if it satisfies the properties of a zero vector. If you don't believe there to be one, we need to prove it.

Let's suppose that there is a zero vector and it is $[x,-x,-x]$. Then for $[1,-1,-1]$ it should be the case that both $$[1,-1,-1]+[x,-x,-x]=[1,-1-x,-1]$$ $$\text{ and }$$ $$[x,-x,-x]+[1,-1,-1]=[x,-1-x,-x]$$ are equal to $[1,-1,-1].$ This would imply that $-1-x=-1$ so $x=0$. However if $x=0$, the second equality fails. Therefore, having a zero vector would be impossible!

( d ) This question is somewhat strange. We have seen that the set has no zero vector! Therefore, it doesn't make sense to try to find inverses for an element under this operation.